# Wordpress: Hide featured image thumbnail from gallery

Tags: php, html, css, wordpress, gallery

```
<div id="imgcontent"> 
<?php my_attachment_gallery(0, 'large', 'alt="' . $post->post_title . '"'); ?> 
</div> <?php endwhile; // end of the loop. ?>
```

I want to exlude the featured image from the gallery, it shows as the first image of the gallery. Is there anyway to do this?

Comment: Can't you just delete it?

Comment: No because I need the featured image as a thumbnail for my main portfolio page.

Answer (score 1):

All of these might help..

```
img{
    width:0px;
    height:0px;
    display:none;
    visibility:hidden;
}
```

More then likely you should only use display none. You should also be using javascript to parse the php to html not php directly, This could leave a huge security flaw.

Note that if you dont want the url to shown, encrypt the url.

Comment: If i do img hide it will hide the rest of my images?